# routingConfig is deprecated in angular2 RC?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea, angular

I try to follow this [tutorial](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/super-fast-setup-angular-2-components-component-router/) to add a bootstrap navbar to my angualr2 app.

I have created my app from the angular2 [quick start](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) page.

Is it better to start over using `angular2 CLI bootstrap`?

However I see lib `routingConfig` is deprecated in angular2 RC.

Is there any simple template\tutorial which is for angualr2?

[image]

Comment: [latest and greatest docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: Also, my advice is to take a tutorial with the latest version if possible, and then get up to date once your tutorial works correctly.
For a simple tutorial, you should the official one which is pretty simple, and try to do what they are asking before watching the solution, it gives a better knowledge imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of use router changed in Angular2RC5.

If you want migrate from RC4 to RC5 you can read the official documentation (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html).

The new way of use router is the following (From the official documentation - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html):

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisCenterComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Heroes List'
    }
  },
  { path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AppComponent }       from './app.component';
import { routing,
         appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';

import { HeroListComponent }    from './hero-list.component';
import { CrisisListComponent }  from './crisis-list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroListComponent,
    CrisisListComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: generally is it better to use angular2 CLI bootsrtap tool?

Comment: I use angular-cli in my projects (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) which is updated to the last version (RC5 = ngModules + new router)